# Ember.Select not binding data in IE8

Tags: ember.js

is there possibly any reason why Ember.Select would bind in firefox/chrome/IE9 but it won't work in IE8?

i'm not able to reproduce this in a jsfiddle. but in my app, this is happening. i have a few nested views and the drop down is in the inner most layer. i verified that the data is there. the markup for the  tags just won't render.

it works when i moved the dropdown up one level to the parent view.

i have another view that render a list of radio options and it's like that as well.

```
{{#each content}}<input type="radio">{{text}}</input>{{/each}}
```

(doesn't work in inner most view but works one level up in parent)

i really can't think of anything that would cause it.

any help would be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Would you mind adding some of your code here?

Comment: That smells a wrong context. Could you try to replace `content` by `view.content` and `text` by `view.text` and tell me if it works ?

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe, here's some code that i compiled. the probably is the App.DateOfBirthField within the App.TravelerContactDetailView. App.DateOfBirthField inherits from Ember.Select http://pastebin.com/FVEXbbaU

Comment: @sly7_7 , i am using view.content so i'm not sure why that is happening. you can look here http://pastebin.com/FVEXbbaU to see my code. thanks!

Comment: You guys are using the helpers on `div` elements.. I didn't know handlebars would work outside the `script` tag or directly injected into Ember.

Comment: I think he posted the differents chunks of code as this, omitting the <script> tag. Anyway, it's difficult to say what's wrong as we don't have all code and templates, in particular these DropDownField and DropDownFieldView.

Comment: my templates are not in script tags because the templates are their own separate files and i use Ember.Handlebars.compile(template) to bring them in to the view. it can't be a context issue right since it works in chrome/firefox/IE9 BUT NOT IE8 :( help?

Comment: @newbiedev so there's no way you can provide a fiddle with a your implementation?

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe i can put something in Jsfiddle but since my app is very modular and large so i wouldn't be simulating a similar environment. i've been trying to reproduce it in JSfiddle but no luck so far. i've gotten as far here in ember.js defaultTemplate: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{#if view.prompt}}<option>{{view.prompt}}</option>{{/if}}{{#each view.content}}{{view Ember.SelectOption contentBinding="this"}}{{/each}}') and it seems like it the {{#each}} helper is not iterating through. doing {{view.content}} displays this <DS.ModelArray:ember5992>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i couldn't figure out why this is happening. my solution was to insert the options manually on didInsertElement.